# How to analyze strongest (honeycomb?) structure?

Tags: structural-engineering, mathematics, strength

To be specific I have a structure consisting of a solid material (eg PLA) consisting of a top horizontal slab (eg 3 cm x 3 cm x 0.5 cm) and a bottom horizontal slab (translated vertically, of the same dimensions) and some yet to be determined connecting structure in between. The volume of the connecting structure is given (eg 5 cm$^3$) and the total height is given (eg 3 cm). What connecting structure will be the strongest - determined by the maximum weight (eg a heavy metal slab) that can be put on top of the upper slab before the structure begins to deform?

I would like to experiment, mathematically, with different connectors - 4 square prisms (at various locations), or 9 (smaller) triangular prisms, or 8 octagonal prisms, cylinders, a hexagonal multi-layer honeycomb, etc etc and compute stresses.

I am looking for references to help me in this mathematical analysis. I prefer not to use structure analysis software, as I would like to write a program to optimize structures. My skills are mathematical, not engineering.

Here is an example of 5 square prisms with side length = $\sqrt 2 /2$ cm $\approx$ 0.71 cm.

[image]

Comment: Your question is about structural optimization but without giving the performance criteria. You stated - "What connecting structure will be the strongest - determined by the maximum weight (eg a heavy metal slab) that can be put on top of the upper slab before the structure begins to deform?", the answer could be "the connecting element shall have a combined area equal to the area of the slab", but I don't think this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @r13 its actually clear from the question - only a certain volume (5 cm³ out of 18, in the example) may be filled.

Comment: @mart so if "fill the space" is the answer, where is the room/need for optimization?

Comment: reread the question carefully.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there are to main schools that tackle this problem. One is structural optimization by the homogenization method, you may find an introductory paper [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-011-4738-5_35). The references therein, the works of Allaire, Gutierrez and Lipton may be of interest. As a disclaimer, my own work is swimming in there somewhere, but it deals on small stiffness contrast, so it's not applicable to this problem.

The other school for these kind of problems is topology optimization, I don't have an introductory reference handy, but the works of Sigmund, Rozvany and others should give you a good starting point.

The [Structural and Multidisciplinary Optimization journal](https://www.springer.com/journal/158) is your best bet to really get into the structural optimization world.

As a caveat, understanding and implementing any of the aforementioned methods would be a 3-6 months job, so I doubt you really want to undertake that particular journal unless you intend to do research in the area. I'd truly recommend using the shape/structural optimization modules of commercial software (like Comsol, Ansys or similar) if you just intend to solve the problem you stated.

Answer (score 0):

```
determined by the maximum weight (eg a heavy metal slab) that can be put on top of the upper slab before the structure begins to deform?
```

Do we have a number to put to the actual allowed deformation (e.g. 2mm)? Or is the upper slab not allowed to deflect at all (mathematically impossible to solve for if you're being very exact with your calcs)?

Also, what exactly is the bottom slab doing ? Is your analysis affected at all by removing it ? If not, you can simplify your problem down to two things:

- Placement of upper slab supports such that deflections are minimal under applied loads, and
- ensuring volume of supports is within the given volume constraints.

For the first part, you'll need equations to calculate the displacement of the top slab segments. FEA (finite element analysis) is your best bet if you want to be really accurate, although there are approximate analytical methods as well if you're okay with sacrificing some accuracy. Have a look at "Roark's formulae for stress and strains" for some excellent (if simple) formulae.